# Create Billing Agreement issue with paypal reference payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

Follow this link :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

First i call the express checkout option that gives me a token id, after that i call the `CreateBillingAgreement($tokenid)` that gives an error like that :

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2017-02-23T11:24:03Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 5cf858da7986
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 64
[BUILD] => 30029726
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 11455
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Buyer did not accept billing agreement
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Buyer did not accept billing agreement
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you redirected the buyer to PayPal checkout page to authorize the billing agreement? As stated in [the guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#billing-agreements):

> The buyer must log into PayPal once to authorize the billing agreement.

You'll need to redirect the buyer's browser to PayPal with the token, which allows the buyer to log into PayPal and authorize the billing agreement, then PayPal redirects the buyer's browser back to your return page(the one you specified in `SetExpressCheckout`). After that you can call `CreateBillingAgreement` with the token.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to be inaccurate, so check that you're passing the correct params.

From their docs:

> &L_BILLINGTYPE0=MerchantInitiatedBilling    #The type of billing agreement
>   &L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=ClubUsage    #The description of the billing agreement

What it should actually be:

> &L_BILLINGTYPE_0=MerchantInitiatedBilling    #The type of billing agreement
>   &L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION_0=ClubUsage    #The description of the billing agreement